# jsf page not refreshed on commandlink click

Tags: jsf, datatable

I want to refresh page on click of activate/deactivate command link,
I used so many tricks but its not getting refresh(fully or partially)
Below is my datatable

```
<h:panelGroup  id="r" >

<h:dataTable id="datatableIterator"  value="#{relationBean.datatables}" var="datatable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" class="role_detail_section">
<h:column>
    <h:dataTable id="relationIterator"  value="#{datatable}" var="item" binding="#{bind}">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"> Relation Type Name</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.relationType}" />

        </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">language</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.language.languageName}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"> Value</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{item.relationForm}" />
        </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bind.rowIndex eq 0}" id="rrr" >
                <p:commandLink ajax="true" action="#{relationBean.deactivateRelationById(item.relationId)}" rendered="#{item.status.statusId==3}" value="Deativate" update="@form rrr" process="@this">
                </p:commandLink> 
                <p:commandLink ajax="true" action="#{relationBean.activateRelationById(item.relationId)}" rendered="#{item.status.statusId==1}" value="Activate" update="@form rrr" process="@this">
                </p:commandLink> 
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
</h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
            <p:commandLink   action="#{relationBean.deleteDataTable}" immediate="true" update="@form" process="@this" ajax="true">
                                <h:graphicImage value="../images/delete.png"  />
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{relationBean.deleteId}" value="#{datatable}" />
                     </p:commandLink>
        </h:column>
```

My bean is viewScoped 
changes are reflects once I press f5 manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [refresh jsf datatable using commandlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094495/refresh-jsf-datatable-using-commandlink)

Comment: Please, edit your previous question instead of duplicating it.